# How to Debug web app tapestry in IntelliJ with jetty runner configuration

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetty, embedded-jetty, tapestry

I'm using intelij as IDE in application tapesrty5 and for server i'm using jetty runner as plugin for intelij
the problem is when i'm trying to run as debug mode the break point never been trigged

Breakpoint created but never been triggered !

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i'm using jetty runner plugin in intelij to run web app aplication tapestry  the problem is when i'm trying to run as debug mode the break points never been trigged